# ReactNative; How to rerender component flipcard after update state

Tags: react-native

I use flipcard(show front - back) to show value but when I change value to show the new one,Flipcard don't back to the front. It still on same page(but value changed)

Example

data1:Front is "A" ,Back is "B"

data2:Front is "X" ,Back is "Y"

I flip A >> B ,Now on flipcard show "B" after that,I update value. Flipcard show "Y" it's not show "X",I have to flip again to "X" . But, I want to show the front of flipcard every new data. How can I do it?

```
 Nextword() {
        
            this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    
        }
```

```
render() {
        return <View>
            <View>
                <CardFlip ref={(card) => this.card = card} >
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.card.flip()}>
                        <Text>{this.state.info[this.state.count].item1}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.card.flip()} >
                        <Text>{this.state.info[this.state.count].item2}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </CardFlip>
            </View >
            <View>
                    <Button title="PRESS1" onPress={this.Nextword.bind(this)}></Button>
                    
            </View>
```

Comment: Can't you simply flip again in `Nextword()`?

Comment: I can flip again in Nextword() but,It see the new data during flip

Comment: I assume you're using `react-native-card-flip`? Then you could flip first and use the `onFlipEnd` event to change the text after flip is complete.

Comment: yes, i using `react-native-card-flip`, Oh I never know the `onFlipEnd` event. I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation example of `react-native-card-flip` I just give a style like this to CardFlip component:

```
style={{
  width: 320,
  height: 470,
}}
```

and fix the issue and card flipped.
below the entire code I try:

```
  <View>
    <CardFlip
      style={{
        width: 320,
        height: 470,
      }}
      ref={(card) => (this.card = card)}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.card.flip()}
        style={{height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <Text>{this.state.info[this.state.count].item1}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{height: 100, width: 100, backgroundColor: 'green'}}
        onPress={() => this.card.flip()}>
        <Text>{this.state.info[this.state.count].item2}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </CardFlip>
  </View>
```

see the documentation example here: https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-flip/blob/master/Example/App.js